# How to use こと　when expressing the experience of something?

Tags: grammar

ｖ．。。。ことが。。。。。

How can i talk about the experience of something using こと?
買うことがｄきます。 would this be the  experience of being able to buy?

If you understand my problem please show me more examples!

Comment: "experience of being able to buy" -- I cannot understand what that means. You should also do the formatting more neatly. What is `v.。。。`? It just looks like garbage. You also have `ｄきます`.

Comment: It is rather difficult to understand your question. Please edit the question to explain "ｖ．。。。ことが。。。。。" and "ｄきます".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I vaguely know what you're trying to find out. You should be looking for:

- ～ことがある

It literally means something like "to have (the experience of) ~"

Verbs:

> Present: 走ることがある - "There are times that (I) run"
>
> Past: 走ったことがある - "There was a time when (I) ran"

い-Adjectives:

> Present: 高いことがある - "There are times when (something) is expensive"
>
> Past: 高かったことがある - "There was a time when (something) was expensive"

な-Adjectives:

> Present: 静かなことがある - "There are times when (something) is quiet"
>
> Past: 静かだったことがある - "There was a time when (something) was quiet"

---

Note that ~ことがある is [structurally ambiguous between being an appositive clause and a relative clause.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3978/542)