# What does 丸ごとアルミホイルで包み mean here?

Tags: grammar, translation, conjugations, phrases

The following is an excerpt from a conversation between me and my language partner:
ニンニクも植えていますので、丸ごとアルミホイルで包み、オーブンで焼いて食べることがあります。

My attempt at translation:
"Because we also grow garlic, we also eat it baking it fully wrapped in aluminium in the oven."

I translated 包み as "wrapped" because I couldn't find a way to translate it as a noun. Even if my translation is right, Im still very confused because there is NOTHING attached to it, no する, no particle, no nothing. I rather expect that my translation is wrong, but then again I don't know how to translate this in a different way.

Then there is "dictionary form (present) + ことがあります"。 I actually only know of た-form + ことがあります. I translated it without any semantical additions, even though I found a source where the "dictionary form (present) + ことがあります" pattern is described: http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-koto-ga-aru/ 
I'm not sure wether I should translate it as it is described there since my sentence is lacking the adverb たまに. However, I got the impression that the "dictionary form (present) + ことがあります" pattern expresses this "there are times..." meaning by itself. But I don't know, so I wanted to ask you^^

Comment: You can rephrase it as 丸ごとアルミホイルで**包んで** 、オーブンで焼いて食べる -- See here for the usage of the continuative form connecting clauses: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9772/9831

Comment: Aand.. for the することがある, this thread will be of some help, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3977/9831

Comment: If you have the book _A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar_ (and every J learner should!), the 包み continuative form is covered in great detail under the entry "Vmasu", I believe.